# Model Naming conflict in CakePHP

Tags: file, cakephp, conflict

Does anybody know if CakePHP 2.x has a naming conflict between a Model named File.php and CakePHP File classes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There's a utility class `File` and the lack of namespacing in CakePHP 2.x means you can't have a second class sharing the same name. You will need to find an alternative name for your model, *e.g.* `Document`.

In CakePHP 3.x this issue is removed as it uses namespaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But, I am having a very weird bug. This line is working perfectly fine from the FilesTemplatesUserTypesController: `$file=$this->FilesTemplatesUserType->File->findByName($name);` but this one: `$file=$this->Draft->Template->TemplatesUserType->FilesTemplatesUserType->findById($ide);` as well as: `$file=$this->Draft->Template->TemplatesUserType->FilesTemplatesUserType->File->findById($ide);` is throwing an error at line 88 in CORE/Utility/File.php, =S. How could this be possible??

Comment: It looks like you're using a model called `File` which is not allowed. As stated in my answer you will need to use an alternative name for the model class.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But why does it work fine from a Controller and fail from a Model? I am bumping my head right now... =S.

Comment: @GerardoCamacho This problem works on a _first come first served_ basis, ie whatever class named `File` is touched first, will be used from then on, so if the model is touched first, `File` will always refer to the model, if the utility class is touched first, `File` will refer to the utility.

Comment: @ndm Thank you very much. Just corroborated that and understood a bunch of bugs. Would you be so kind to post the same answer in this question so I can mark it as correct?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214074/intermitent-naming-conflict